# NSRangeException related to UIActionSheet

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using `UIActionSheet` to display 3 action buttons in a popover when a table row is selected.

In .h of my `tableViewController`, I have declared the following:

```
UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
```

In .m of my `tableViewController`, I have the following code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (self.actionSheet == nil) {  
self.actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                         initWithTitle:@"Available Actions" 
             delegate:self 
             cancelButtonTitle:nil 
             destructiveButtonTitle:@"Delete" 
             otherButtonTitles:@"Button1", @"Button2", nil] ;
}
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect popoverRect = [[cell superview] convertRect:cell.frame toView:self.tableView];
[self.actionSheet showFromRect:popoverRect inView:self.tableView animated:YES];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [self.actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]; 

    if ([buttonTitle compare:@"button1"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        //...DO Something

    } else if ([buttonTitle compare:@"button2"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        //...Do sometihing

        }else {
        //...
    }
}
```

---

The Action Sheet does show up correctly after selecting a table row, however, it crashes if I click on anywhere outside the action sheet, and the console displays the following:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 
'*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (-1( or possibly larger)) beyond bounds (3)'
```

In comparision, it does NOT crash and the action sheet popover gets dismissed correctly when I click on any buttons on the action sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use buttonTitleAtIndex: and don't compare button titles (they might be localized). Just compare buttonIndex to a number corresponding to actual button index, using destructiveButtonIndex and firstOtherButtonIndex properties.

Answer (score 0):

Check if buttonIndex == -1 and if it is redisplay your actionsheet rather than your methods current code.